# How to sync Apple Address Book with WP7 Phone?

Tags: macos, contacts, address-book, windows-phone

I'm on a Mac, how do I sync my Apple Address Book contacts with the contacts on my Windows Phone 7 phone?

Comment: Microsoft seems to think you only use your Mac for [Media](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1fe7ea0f-3ad6-4137-8397-d412a3792c33). According to [this comment thread](http://www.neowin.net/news/hands-on-windows-phone-7-connector-for-mac-beta-due-october-24), Windows Phone 7 syncs contacts only with "the cloud". The better questions therefore would be, "How do I sync OS X Address Book with cloud services supported by Windows Phone 7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this as Daniel suggested - syncing with "the cloud" instead.  I synced my Apple Address Book with my Contacts in my Google account, then synced my Google account with my phone.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this at the moment.

You really need a way to sync your contacts with your live account. If you could sync your Apple Address Book with Outlook you could use the connector pack to keep outlook and live in sync. Instructions on doing this at http://johnprice.biz/weblog/2010/10/27/syncing-outlook-calendar-with-windows-phone-7/

Answer (score 1):

Your address book has the ability to sync with google, as does your windows phone 7. That is what I have been doing and it works great.